# Nginx Configuration: Is it possible to enable Gzip with HTTPS

Tags: nginx, https, gzip, http2

Hello I know Gzip over https/SSL is unsecured but my server runs just one blog that is a static file website with so there is no security risk.

So what I would like to do is use both https fro http_v2 and Gzip in my Nginx server configuration.

Does anyone know how to enable them both as it seems that Gzip by default only runs with http?

Thanks

Comment: Who said that? Everyone uses gzip and https without any problems

Comment: @AlexeyTen http://breachattack.com/

Comment: There are so many conditions and none of them applies to simple static site.

Answer (score 0):

The attacks allow attacker to guess the content (like cookies). If you don't store anything confidential in them, you can safely activate Gzip.